# Multiple commands in a given sign doesn't execute correctly...?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Well, as you probably know, `ArmorStand`'s with `CustomName`'s are used to create holograms. I am trying to make a one command sign generator that creates a multiline hologram, multiple `ArmorStand`'s under each other. The generator nearly works, as it returns a result. The command is quite long, so you can go read it on [Pastebin by clicking here](http://pastebin.com/DtF1FcdX). The problem is that the `ArmorStand`'s above the lowest one doesn't teleport.

**To make it simpler**

Let's say I have these commands:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:bottom,NoGravity:1,Passengers:[{id:Zombie,Passengers:[{id:"ArmorStand",NoGravity:1,CustomName:top}]}]}

/kill @e[type=Zombie]

/execute @e[name=bottom] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[name=top] ~ ~-3 ~
```

And I put it into a sign using [this sign generator.](http://minecraft.tools/en/sign.php) The result won't be the same as when I execute the commands each by hand. For an example [click here](http://minecraft.tools/en/sign.php?sign=%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22color%3A%233E3EB7%22%3EClick%3Cbr%20%2F%3EHere%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%26nbsp%3B&command=%2Fsummon%20ArmorStand%20~%20~%20~%20%7BCustomName%3Abottom%2CNoGravity%3A1%2CPassengers%3A%5B%7Bid%3AZombie%2CPassengers%3A%5B%7Bid%3A%22ArmorStand%22%2CNoGravity%3A1%2CCustomName%3Atop%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%0A%0A%2Fkill%20%40e%5Btype%3DZombie%5D%0A%0A%2Fexecute%20%40e%5Bname%3Dbottom%5D%20~%20~%20~%20%2Ftp%20%40e%5Bname%3Dtop%5D%20~%20~-3%20~&signname=). What is the problem here?

Answer (score -1):

First of all if you execute all of them from one sign in different lines, then you need to do it sign by sign. If you want them to execute from one line (all at once) I suggest you place a redstone block with a setblock that activates a command block chain.